# Get Department of user from AD

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, active-directory

Working with Active directory in an ASP.net CORE MVC website,
I can get many user property like diplayName, emailAdress...
But I cannot find the departement of the user.
**Get user informations** :

```
UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain), Environment.UserName);
```

But user haven't a property "Department".

I've try :

```
DirectoryEntry directoryEntry = user.GetUnderlyingObject() as DirectoryEntry;
        var property = "department";
        if (directoryEntry.Properties.Contains(property))
        {
            var dep = directoryEntry.Properties[property].Value.ToString();
        }
```

No departement property neither.

**EDIT**

Here's a list of properties available : `"objectClass, cn, sn, title, description, userCertificate, givenName, distinguishedName, instanceType, whenCreated, whenChanged, displayName, uSNCreated, memberOf, uSNChanged, proxyAddresses, homeMDB, mDBUseDefaults, mailNickname, name, objectGUID, userAccountControl, badPwdCount, codePage, countryCode, badPasswordTime, lastLogon, pwdLastSet, primaryGroupID, objectSid, accountExpires, logonCount, sAMAccountName, sAMAccountType, showInAddressBook, legacyExchangeDN, userPrincipalName, objectCategory, dSCorePropagationData, lastLogonTimestamp, textEncodedORAddress, mail and Lot of msExchange"`

Comment: It could be related to the AD entry or related to your code. Your code looks fine to me. If the AD data does not have the value you want to check I suggest you elaborate what the problem is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This works for me (using a mixture of `AccountManagement` and `DirectoryServices`):

```
var ad = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, DOMAIN);
var u  = new UserPrincipal(ad) {SamAccountName = Environment.UserName};

using (var search = new PrincipalSearcher(u))
{
    var user = (UserPrincipal) search.FindOne();

    DirectoryEntry dirEntry = (DirectoryEntry)user.GetUnderlyingObject();
    string dept = dirEntry.Properties["Department"].Value.ToString();
    Console.WriteLine(dept);
}
```

This requires the following `using`:

```
using System;
using System.DirectoryServices;
using System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement;
```

Comment: Not better, I'haven't any "Department" property, check the Edit.

Comment: @Alexis If you do not have the property, how do you spect to acess it???

Comment: @bradbury9 The problem is I don't know if this property exist, it doesn't appear with my code but the IT Technician  say it exist.

Comment: Either it does not exist, or the user that tries to access it does not have right to it. I would double-check with IT.

Comment: I've check with the IT, my department was not entered, so problem solved, I put your answer as corrrect. If a field is not fill, it doesn't appear. Why just Microsoft make it appear empty ?

Answer (score 0):

To search for an employee's unit

Use value

```
Department = directoryEntry.Properties["subdivision"].Value as string,
```